# What is the best way to set notifications in android

Tags: android, notifications

I'm making an app that remind a close forum with something like 100 users. Every time a user is asking a question, the app needs to send notification for all the users that taking place in his close forum, that going to be a lot of notification that send Simultaneously.
Does anybody know what is the best way to set that kind of notification in android? Maybe every time the database is updating, or update the user app every 3 min. I need that the users will get the notification as soon as they can.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Notifications can be broadly put under two categories push notifications and pull notifications.

Push: This would require server action based on the event, check Google Cloud Messaging

Pull:  Where you run a service on the device and keep on pinging the server after a certain interval for data.

In your scenario, if the notification required is not real-time you might want to go with Pull notification albeit with something like 10 minutes interval even more. Lesser the interval, more battery and data charges for the user. In case real-time notification is required you can go with Push.

Comment: I need the notification will be in real time. But isn't it problem that something like 100 users will get notification Simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

If you have acces to web resource you can use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging, http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to push messages to your android clients. So it will not drain so much power, as pulling mode.

If you have not, the best way is to retreive data by some interval and notify user about data changing. Also you can retreive only header `Content-Length` and compare with previous value to prevent for loading all page

Comment: I need the notification will be in real time. But isn't it problem that something like 100 users will get notification Simultaneously?

Comment: Yes! it's not a problem. Your web service pushes notifications to all devices simultaneously (If you would use GCM)